# Spring's MappingMongoConverter documentation

Tags: spring, mongodb, converters, spring-data-mongodb

Can anybody explain how the `MappingMongoConverter` (`Spring's` default implementation of the `MongoConverter` interface) works for the cases where the mapping between POJO and Document isn't so trivial? Example cases: a POJO has an additional field it can't find in the Document, the Document has a structure that doesn't fit to the POJO,...

[The official Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html) seems to lack this information.

Example code:

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
    DBObject obj = cursor.next(); 
    Foo foo = mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(Foo.class, obj);  
    returnList.add(foo); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is lacking, so had to dive into the source. I'll share my work.The tricky part is the POJO to BSON conversion:

The first thing it does is look for a `@PersistenceConstructor` annotation on a constructor. If no preferred constructor is set, the no arg constructor is used. The no mapping of the no arg constructor is simple enough. **For the mapping of the preferred constructor, all parameters have to be present in the `BSON`**. If a parameter can not be found, a `MappingException` will be thrown. **This means that the `BSON` file can contain extra fields that don't have to map to a constructor parameter.** Those parameters will just be ignored.